# How to Deal with Case Sensitive of a property in Maven POM.xml

Tags: java, maven

I working on a  maven project that requires a SystemPropertyVariable(maven-surefire-plugin) to be set at the command line(-Dinstance=$instance) and passing value in CAPs as below

> mvn test -Dinstance=UAT

```
 <build>
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <argLine>-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
              <!--  Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <instance>${instance}</instance>
                    <urltype>${urltype}</urltype>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
 </build>
```

I need to convert that string into all lowercase before or in compile phase so that it can be used across different files or even pass as argument for other jar file as input which is used in same project

NOTE: as i said before it will be passed as argument to another jar file  as input from POM . so i want to convert to lowercase in POM before using in that jar and then it will be used in test from the data file it generates.

Please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: `${instance}` must be a property in your code, you should be able to edit it, no?

Comment: as i said before it will be passed as argument to another jar file as input from POM . so i want to convert to lowercase in POM before using in that jar and then it will be used in test from the data file it generates.

Comment: You can manipulate a property with `build-helper:regex-property`, but I do not not whether you can convert it to lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate properties with groovy via gmaven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-dynamic-properties</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scripts>
                    <script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            instance = "${instance}"
                            lcInstance = instance.toLowerCase()
                            project.properties.setProperty('lcInstance', lcInstance)
                        ]]>
                    </script>
                </scripts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

${lcInstance} now contains the lower case copy of ${instance}

Comment: when i tried the above code getting the following error --- [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.6.2:execute (add-dynamic-properties) on project Sample: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath. InvocationTargetException: Cannot invoke method toLowerCase() on null object -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   using mvn test -Dinstance=UAT

Comment: Edited. Use instance="${instance}". The previous form works only if the property is defined inside the pom.xml